# Parse JSON Facebook Conversations XCODE

Tags: xcode, facebook, json, message, feed

I need your help. I can parse correctly the graph.facebook.com/me/feed JSON, but i can't do it with graph.facebook.com/me/conversations. Can you please help me? this is how i get the last message from feed

```
 NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                                       options:kNilOptions
                                                                         error:nil];
                  NSLog(@"json %@", json);
                  NSDictionary *items = [json objectForKey:@"data"];
                  // NSDictionary *item = [items objectAtIndex:1];

                  NSLog(@"items %@", items);


                  NSMutableArray *story = [NSMutableArray array];

                  for (NSDictionary *item in items )
                  {

                      if([item objectForKey:@"message"] || [item objectForKey:@"message"] != nil || [[item objectForKey:@"message"] length]>0)
                      {
                          [story addObject:[item objectForKey:@"message"]];
                      }
                      else{

                          NSLog(@"no message");
                      }

                  }
                  NSLog(@"story %@", story);

                  NSString *lastMessage = [story objectAtIndex:0];
                  NSLog(@"lastmessage received is %@", lastMessage);
```

Can you please help me? Thanks

EDIT: I get this error in NSString *lastMessage = [story objectAtIndex:0];

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for
>   empty array'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x341fc2a3 0x3aede97f 0x34147b75 0xc3a1d 0x3add2d91 0x3c22c11f 0x3c22fecf 0x3c22fdc1 0x3c23091d 0x3c230ac1
>   0x3ae54a11 0x3ae548a4) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an
>   exception

NSLog from "items" is the following:

```
(
        {
        "can_reply" = 1;
        id = "t_id.xx5719286166414";
        "is_subscribed" = 1;
        link = "http://www.facebook.com/messages/?action=read&tid=id.xx5719286166414";
        "message_count" = 4;
        messages =         {
            data =             (
                                {
                    "created_time" = "2012-11-30T17:53:00+0000";
                    from =                     {
                        email = "1367741936@facebook.com";
                        id = 1367741936;
                        name = " xxx xxx";
                    };
                    id = "m_msg.fe83b318fa94e6bbcc90a9a52fa4645b01";
                    message = "Questo \U00e8 un messaggio";
                    tags =                     {
                        data =                         (
                                                        {
                                name = inbox;
                            },
                                                        {
                                name = messenger;
                            },
                                                        {
                                name = read;
                            },
                                                        {
                                name = "source:mobile";
                            }
                        );
                    };
                    to =                     {
                        data =                         (
                                                        {
                                email = "100004765716168@facebook.com";
                                id = 100004765716168;
                                name = "AccountDevelopment Development";
                            },
                                                        {
                                email = "1367741936@facebook.com";
                                id = 1367741936;
                                name = " xxx xxx";
                            }
                        );
                    };
                },
                                {
                    "created_time" = "2012-11-29T11:49:00+0000";
                    from =                     {
                        email = "1367741936@facebook.com";
                        id = 1367741936;
                        name = " xxx xxx";
                    };
                    id = "m_id.128631660627297";
                    message = "funziona?";
                    tags =                     {
                        data =                         (
                                                        {
                                name = inbox;
                            },
                                                        {
                                name = read;
                            },
                                                        {
                                name = "source:web";
                            }
                        );
                    };
                    to =                     {
                        data =                         (
                                                        {
                                email = "100004765716168@facebook.com";
                                id = 100004765716168;
                                name = "AccountDevelopment Development";
                            },
                                                        {
                                email = "1367741936@facebook.com";
                                id = 1367741936;
                                name = " xxx xxx";
                            }
                        );
                    };
                },
                                {
                    "created_time" = "2012-11-28T18:05:57+0000";
                    from =                     {
                        email = "1367741936@facebook.com";
                        id = 1367741936;
                        name = " xxx xxx";
                    };
                    id = "m_id.141590452655798";
                    message = "prova messaggio";
                    tags =                     {
                        data =                         (
                                                        {
                                name = inbox;
                            },
                                                        {
                                name = read;
                            },
                                                        {
                                name = "source:web";
                            }
                        );
                    };
                    to =                     {
                        data =                         (
                                                        {
                                email = "100004765716168@facebook.com";
                                id = 100004765716168;
                                name = "AccountDevelopment Development";
                            },
                                                        {
                                email = "1367741936@facebook.com";
                                id = 1367741936;
                                name = " xxx xxx";
                            }
                        );
                    };
                },
                                {
                    "created_time" = "2012-11-28T18:04:50+0000";
                    from =                     {
                        email = "1367741936@facebook.com";
                        id = 1367741936;
                        name = " xxx xxx";
                    };
                    id = "m_id.xx5719286166414";
                    message = "Ciao Francesco, come stai?";
                    tags =                     {
                        data =                         (
                                                        {
                                name = inbox;
                            },
                                                        {
                                name = read;
                            },
                                                        {
                                name = "source:web";
                            }
                        );
                    };
                    to =                     {
                        data =                         (
                                                        {
                                email = "100004765716168@facebook.com";
                                id = 100004765716168;
                                name = "AccountDevelopment Development";
                            },
                                                        {
                                email = "1367741936@facebook.com";
                                id = 1367741936;
                                name = " xxx xxx";
                            }
                        );
                    };
                }
            );
            paging =             {
                next = "https://graph.facebook.com/t_id.xx5719286166414/messages?access_token=BAABlotMxL1MBACbrnuvICOwBKjkw68ZBaqLOY2MVE6tga8xPmiF9VWH7RZAZCoZBDeSD29KWTzuze3xpjP7xb1kmfyw7VYtvGZC0E1gwgJthpZAoKoFXAYanGcBMb1qzO7SBAI3WPLcLAq7yAUpyF9NiHY0vIpsiGJZASx3eZCA83Lm18hpjmo0K97ZBSOiAoYeZCm2vYDgqq4S8jqOvZCvGZCZByNeg4ElNiSwZA1hHqdA6qrFAZDZD&limit=25&until=1354125890&__paging_token=m_id.xx5719286166414";
                previous = "https://graph.facebook.com/t_id.xx5719286166414/messages?access_token=BAABlotMxL1MBACbrnuvICOwBKjkw68ZBaqLOY2MVE6tga8xPmiF9VWH7RZAZCoZBDeSD29KWTzuze3xpjP7xb1kmfyw7VYtvGZC0E1gwgJthpZAoKoFXAYanGcBMb1qzO7SBAI3WPLcLAq7yAUpyF9NiHY0vIpsiGJZASx3eZCA83Lm18hpjmo0K97ZBSOiAoYeZCm2vYDgqq4S8jqOvZCvGZCZByNeg4ElNiSwZA1hHqdA6qrFAZDZD&limit=25&since=1354297980&__paging_token=m_msg.fe83b318fa94e6bbcc90a9a52fa4645b01&__previous=1";
            };
        };
        participants =         {
            data =             (
                                {
                    email = "1367741936@facebook.com";
                    id = 1367741936;
                    name = " xxx xxx";
                },
                                {
                    email = "100004765716168@facebook.com";
                    id = 100004765716168;
                    name = "AccountDevelopment Development";
                }
            );
        };
        senders =         {
            data =             (
                                {
                    email = "1367741936@facebook.com";
                    id = 1367741936;
                    name = " xxx xxx";
                }
            );
        };
        snippet = "Questo \U00e8 un messaggio";
        tags =         {
            data =             (
                                {
                    name = inbox;
                },
                                {
                    name = read;
                },
                                {
                    name = seen;
                },
                                {
                    name = "source:web";
                }
            );
        };
        "updated_time" = "2012-11-30T17:53:00+0000";
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a level in your accessors. The top level item in the JSON is `messages`, and that contains `data`. And then `data` is an array, not a dictionary. So you should change the first lines to this...

```
NSArray *messageGroups = [json objectForKey:@"data"];
NSDictionary* firstMessageGroup = [messageGroups objectAtIndex:0];
NSDictionary *messages = [firstMessageGroup objectForKey:@"messages"];
NSArray* items = [messages objectForKey@"data"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. This is what i get:
`code
2012-12-04 18:35:38.126 WebView[700:5a03] items (null)
2012-12-04 18:35:38.129 WebView[700:5a03] story (
)
2012-12-04 18:35:38.132 WebView[700:5a03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x335332a3 0x3a21597f 0x3347eb75 0xdb9cd 0x3a109d91 0x3b56311f 0x3b566ecf 0x3b566dc1 0x3b56791d 0x3b567ac1 0x3a18ba11 0x3a18b8a4)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception `

Comment: does `messages` contain a valid object. Can you log it?

Comment: `2012-12-05 10:24:20.372 WebView[191:6a03] messages (null)`

Comment: sorry I thought you were logging the json object. I think I've fixed the code now

Comment: Sorry, no. I get this error `2012-12-05 18:40:58.182 WebView[1418:8a63] -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1eda56b0
2012-12-05 18:40:58.184 WebView[1418:8a63] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1eda56b0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x334532a3 0x3a13597f 0x33456e07 0x33455531 0x333acf68 0x68d73 0x3a029d91 0x3b48311f 0x3b486ecf 0x3b486dc1 0x3b48791d 0x3b487ac1 0x3a0aba11 0x3a0ab8a4)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception`

Comment: I get it in `NSDictionary *messages = [topdata objectForKey:@"messages"];`